# Silex, how to set JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE in json()

Tags: php, silex

In PHP I can use `JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE` in `json_encode();`

How I can do that in Silex Framework with `$app->json()` ?

Thanks.

Comment: Hello, please take a time to go through the [welcome tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) to know your way around here , read how to create a [mcve] example and also check [ask] so you increase your chances to get feedback and useful answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As i know - you cannot do that in silex. Use json_encode() instead. But if you will find better solution, share it please.

Comment: Thx. I googled last hour and find nothing. Even in official documentation.

Answer (score 1):

`$app->json()` is just a wrapper for `JsonResponse`.

You can build `JsonResponse` manually:

```
$response = new \Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\JsonResponse($data);
$response->setEncodingOptions(JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);
return $response;
```